# Ist die Bedeutung von "verräumen" als "wegräumen und dann nicht wiederfinden" regional?

Tags: meaning, regional

Kürzlich begegnete mir die folgende Aussage eines öffentlichen Betriebes:

> Sie können Ihre XYZ bei uns abgeben; wir verräumen sie gerne für Sie.

Als ich das las, musste ich zunächst mal herzhaft lachen - nicht zuletzt, weil es in der Vergangenheit bei der betreffenden Einrichtung schon des öfteren vorgekommen war, dass unsere dort abgegebenen Sachen nicht oder nicht gleich wiedergefunden wurden, als sie gebraucht wurden.

Ich kannte das Wort "verräumen" bislang *ausschließlich* in der Bedeutung, in der das "ver-" einen Misserfolg ausdrückt - ähnlich wie in "sich verlaufen", "sich verrechnen", "etwas verschütten" oder "etwas verregnen", wenn mit diesen Worten ein entsprechender Misserfolg zum Ausdruck gebracht werden soll.

Als ungefähr synonym mit "verräumen" würde ich (in absteigender Reihenfolge) "etwas verlegen" (im Sinn von "etwas irgendwo hinlegen und dann nicht mehr wissen, wohin"), "etwas verbummeln" (ugs.), "etwas verschlampern" und "etwas verlieren" sehen.

**Wenn man etwas verräumt hat, dann hat man es *irgendwo* hingeräumt, weiß aber nicht mehr, wohin.**

---

Offensichtlich meinte der Schreiber des Textes aber etwas anderes, nämlich ganz neutral "aufräumen". Überrascht stellte ich nach kurzer Recherche fest, dass beispielsweise [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verr%C3%A4umen) als Synonyme von "verräumen" allerdings "einräumen", "einsortieren", "unterbringen" und weitere nennt, von denen kein einziges die Bedeutung des "Scheiterns durch Verschlampern" hat.

**Ist die mir (bislang als einzige) bekannte Bedeutung von "verräumen" regional begrenzt, z.B. auf Südwestdeutschland, wo ich den Großteil meines Lebens verbracht und meine sprachliche Prägung erhalten habe?**

Comment: kann es nicht beantworten, weil aus Südwestdeutschland (BaWü) und mir diese Bedeutung von "verräumen" als "verstauen" oder "wegräumen" absolut geläufig ist... das lässt leider keinerlei Rückschlüsse auf andere Regionen zu

Comment: Nur damit dir die Bedeutungen nicht ausgehen: Das Schweizerische Idiotikon listet noch eine weitere auf, nämlich als Synonym für "anberaumen". Ich kannte bisher auch nur "aufräumen und nie wiederfinden", komme aber auch aus dem Südwesten.

Comment: Ich wohne in Nordbaden und kenne nur den Sinn "verstauen" oder "wegräumen", nicht "aufräumen und nie wiederfinden".

Comment: Ich komme ursprünglich aus Nordostdeutschland und habe das Verb "verräumen" in meinem Leben noch nie verwendet. Ich kann allenfalls raten, was der Beispielsatz bedeuten soll.

Comment: In der Schweiz ist mir das Wort nur in der Bedeutung ‘wegräumen’ geläufig, ohne Konnotation von ‘verschlampen’.

Comment: Mir geht es wie @Tode - ich bin in BaWü aufgewachsen und kenne "verräumen" nur als "einsortieren"; gelernt habe ich das Wort, als ich Ende der 80er in einem Heilbronner Supermarkt Ferienjobs gemacht habe. Mittlerweile in Berlin, und hier habe ich das im Alltag in keiner der möglichen Bedeutungen je gehört.

Answer (score 1):

> Ist die mir (bislang als einzige) bekannte Bedeutung von "verräumen" regional begrenzt, z.B. auf Südwestdeutschland

Ich kann versichern, daß in sämtlichen Teilen Österreichs, die ich kenne, die von Dir geschilderte Bedeutung die einzig plausible ist.

Ich stimme zwar Deiner Meinung, daß

> das "ver-" einen Misserfolg ausdrückt

nicht uneingeschränkt zu - dem Umstand, daß beim Bau der Staumauer viele Tonnen Beton *verbaut* wurden, läßt mich nicht deren Einsturz fürchten. Dieses Gefühl hätte ich im Gegenteil eher, wenn weniger davon *verbraucht* worden wäre.

Im Falle von "verräumen" stimme ich allerdings zu, daß das ein "Einräumen" oder "Hinräumen" beschreibt, bei dem die Aussicht auf Wiederauffinden begrenzt ist - nicht notwendigerweise durch den Verräumer selbst, eventuell auch durch andere, im Sinne von "verstecken".

Andererseits wird etwa in der Schweiz "verzeigt", wo in anderen Ländern "angezeigt" wird. Das ist zwar (oft) für den Verzeigten durchaus betrüblich, aber ein Mißerfolg (wenigstens für den, der zur Polizei gegangen ist und Meldung erstattet hat) muß damit nicht verbunden sein.

Comment: Kleine Klarstellung: Ich hab' nirgendwo behauptet, dass "ver-" *immer* auf einen Misserfolg hindeute. Sondern nur, dass es in "verräumen" der Fall ist, genau wie in einer Reihe (aber sicherlich nicht allen) weiteren Wörtern.

Comment: OK, dann habe ich Dich mißverstanden.

Comment: Aber es ist interessant, dass du nochmal eine weitere Bedeutung aufzählst - beim "Verstecken" ist das Nichtwiederfinden ja zweifellos beabsichtigt und wie gesagt nicht notwendigerweise auf den Verräumer bezogen; also etwas anderes als das mir bekannte versehentliche Verräumen, das nie so beabsichtigt war.

Answer (score 1):

In den DWDS-Korpora (Berliner Tagesspiegel) findet sich:

> Der Tagesspiegel, 13.07.2015
> Zum Beispiel bei Edeka: "Schüler ab 16 können bei uns an der Kasse arbeiten oder  beim Verräumen von Waren helfen", sagt Edeka-Sprecherin Marlies Poppe.

sowie

> Der Tagesspiegel, 04.02.2015
> Mehrere Medien hatten berichtet, dass die künftig für das Verräumen der Waren zuständigen Mitarbeiter "wie bei Amazon" nach den Tarifen der Logistikbranche behandelt werden könnten.

Daher sehe ich den Teil des *Nichtwiederfindens* als offenbar nicht zwingende Bedeutung.

Das bestätigen auch die zahlreichen Treffer des [DWDS Webkorpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=web&q=verr%C3%A4umen).

Auch beim *Verschütten* gibt es noch die andere Bedeutung wie *von der Lawine/dem Erdrutsch zugedeckt*, die anders gelagert scheint.

Comment: Das beantwortet nicht wirklich die Frage - dass "verräumen" offenbar mitunter auch anders verstanden wird, hatte ich ja bereits herausgefunden. Die Frage dreht sich ja nun darum, in welchem Kontext das Wort die mir bislang geläufige Bedeutung hat - geographisch begrenzt z.B.? Davon abgesehen fällt übrigens auf, dass beide Beispiele in dieser Antwort auch weniger der Alltagssprache als vielmehr dem Fachjargon aus Einzelhandel und Logistik zu entstammen scheinen.

Comment: "Auch beim *Verschütten* gibt es noch die andere Bedeutung" - aber natürlich. Und auch "sich verlaufen" hat als weitere Bedeutung "sich zerstreuen", "sich verteilen" (z.B. "die Menge verläuft sich"). Da drückt das "ver-" aber keinen Misserfolg aus - ich nahm an, dass ich bei den aufgezählten Beispielen auf genau die Bedeutung abzielte, in der das "ver-" ebenso einen Misserfolg ausdrückt, wäre durch den einleitenden Text klar geworden. Ich habe den Absatz nochmal angepasst, um das eindeutiger zu machen.

Comment: Zumindest kann ich bestätigen, dass mir als Berliner die Wortverwendung des Tagesspiegels vertraut, wenn auch etwas technisch vorkommt, die Interpretation als Misserfolg jedoch unbekannt war.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, das scheint regional zu sein.

Ich habe das Wort "verräumen" in diesem Zusammenhang / mit dieser Bedeutung noch nie gehört oder gelesen, bin gebürtiger Hamburger und lebe nach wie vor im Norden Deutschlands.

Bei uns sagt man einräumen, einsortieren, verstauen.

Und mit anderer Bedeutung: Verbummeln, verlegen, verschlampen.