# Kann man neue Wörter mit Präfixen und Suffixen schaffen?

Tags: word-usage, prefix

Wenn ich irgendeinen von diesen Sätze sagen würde, würden die Leute mich noch verstehen?

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich **verwasche** eine grasige Fleck auf meiner bläuigen Hose, sodaß niemand die **ausmerkt**.

> Es is unglaublich, wie Leute miteinander **erquatschen** werden, wann der Präsident eine **kleinchenliche** Tomate im Salat **verhasse**.

Ich versuche herauszufinden, ob ich mehrere Wörter wie diese nutzen kann.

Comment: Weißt du denn selbst, was das heißen soll? Wenn nicht, wieso sollen andere dann besser verstehen was du sagst als du selbst?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ui, das ist sehr gefährlich!!! Lass das lieber. Wir Muttersprachler machen das auch nur äußerst selten, und das aus gutem Grund. Wenn du die deutsche Sprache noch nicht perfekt beherrscht, ist die Chance sehr hoch, dass du mit dieser Methode auf eines dieser beiden Probleme triffst:

1. Das von dir erfundene Wort existiert bereits, bedeutet aber nicht das, was du glaubst.

   Ein Beispiel dafür ist das Wort [verwaschen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verwaschen), das bereits im deutschen Wortschaft vorhanden ist. Es ist zwar ein Adjektiv, und kein Verb, wie in deinem Satz, aber aus dem existierenden Adjektiv kann man leicht ein Verb ableiten. Dieses Verb hatt dann aber nicht die Bedeutung, die es vermutlich in deinem Satz haben soll.

   - existierendes Adjektiv *»verwaschen«*

     - Ursprüngliche Bedeutung: Durch häufiges Waschen bleich geworden (»Susis Kleid sieht schon ziemlich verwaschen aus.«)
     - Davon abgeleitete Bedeutung: Undeutlich sichtbar (*»In dem dichten Nebel waren die Konturen des Mannes nur sehr verwaschen zu erkennen.«*)
     - Übertrage Bedeutung: Unklar (*»Dr. Gruber hat in seinem Vortrag sehr verwaschene Formulierungen verwendet.«*)
   - davon abgeleitetes Verb *»verwaschen«*, das nicht in Wörterbüchern zu finden ist, aber trotzdem verstanden wird, weil es sich auf das existierende Adjektiv bezieht

     > Du wirst die Farben des Kleides verwaschen, wenn du es immer so heißt wäscht.

     Damit ist gemeint, dass die Farben durch häufiges Waschen blasser werden.
   - deine Verwendung

     > Ich verwasche einen Fleck auf meiner Hose

     Ich vermute, dass damit folgendes gemeint sein soll: *»Auf meiner Hose ist ein Fleck, und den beseitige ich durch Waschen.«*
     Tatsächlich werden deutsche Muttersprachler aber eher folgendes verstehen: *»Ich wasche die Hose, und dadurch wird der Fleck blasser und seine Konturen werden undeutlicher, aber der Fleck ist danach immer noch zu sehen.«*

   Tatsächlich gibt es im Deutschen aber bereits ein Verb, das genau die Bedeutung hat, die du vermutlich suchst. Es ist das trennbare Verb *»auswaschen«*:

   > falsch: Ich verwasche eine grasige Fleck auf meiner bläuigen Hose.
   > richtig: Ich **wasche einen grasigen** Fleck **aus** meiner **bläulichen** Hose **aus.**

   (Präsens: *»Ich **wasche** den Fleck aus der Hose **aus.**«* Futur I: *»Ich werde den Fleck aus der Hose **auswaschen.**«*)
2. Das von dir erfundene Wort folgt keinem etablierten Muster

   Das ist bei allen anderen von dir genannten Beispielen der Fall. Die Wörter *»ausmerken«* und *»erquatschen«* folgen zwar noch syntaktisch etablierten Wortbildungsmustern, führen aber zu Ergebnissen, die semantisch mit keinerlei etablierten Bedeutungen belegt sind. Solche Wörter können allerhöchstens dann mit der von dir gewollten Bedeutung erkannt werden, wenn du im Kontext ausreichende und sehr präzise Hinweise lieferst.

   Die Beispiele *»kleinchenliche«* und *»verhasse«* verletzen sogar syntaktische Grundregeln. Sie sind einfach nur falsch. (Das Verb *»verhasse«* wäre syntaktisch möglich, wenn das Subjekt in der ersten Person stünde, aber das ist in deinem Satz nicht der Fall)

Answer (score 5):

Es ist im Deutschen grundsätzlich möglich, mit Präfixen und Suffixen neue Wörter zu bilden.

**Aber:** Das erfordert sehr gute Deutschkenntnisse und ein gutes Sprachgefühl, damit es vom muttersprachlichen Leser nicht nur verstanden, sondern auch als stilistisch akzeptabel betrachtet wird.

Außerdem sollte es sehr sparsam eingesetzt werden. Die in der Frage gegebenen Beispiele wirken für einen Muttersprachler sehr seltsam.

Ich würde es daher niemandem empfehlen, dessen Deutschniveau unterhalb von C2 liegt.

Answer (score 2):

### Kann man das machen?

Ja. Diese Art des kreativen Sprachgebrauchs ist möglich. Beispiele sind vor allem in der Dichtung anzutreffen. Spontan fallen mir zwei Gedichte von Erich Fried ein, dessen Werk besonders durch kreative Sprachverwendung gekennzeichnet ist. Erstens das Gedicht *Erstickübung*:

> Tief denken
> eindenken
> ausdenken
> jetzt nur mehr flach denken
> Flach eindenken
> ausdenken
> eindenken
> jetzt nicht mehr ausdenken
> schön stillhalten
> so bleiben
> überhaupt nicht mehr
> denken
> oder nur
> an etwas ganz anderes

Das Gedicht spielt mit einer sehr einfach erkennbaren und klar markierten Analogie von *denken* und *atmen*, sodass sich die Bedeutung der Verben *eindenken* (das es so nicht gibt) und *ausdenken* (das eine andere Bedeutung hat) leicht erklärt.

Ein zweites Beispiel für die kreative Verwendung von Präfixen, ebenfalls von Erich Fried, ist das Gedicht *Verstandsaufnahme*, in welchem Fried konsequent die Präfixe *be-* und *ver-* vertauscht und damit erzielt, dass die Bedeutung der jeweiligen Verben aktualisiert wird - man liest diese Verben dann so, als würde man sie zum ersten Mal lesen. Auch ergeben sich bedeutungstragende Spannungen wenn die Variante mit vertauschtem Präfix sinntragend ist - etwa, weil das Verb mit dem anderen Präfix tatsächlich existiert (etwa in *Beschwörer* statt *Verschwörer*, oder bei *verkannt* statt *bekannt*) oder existieren könnte, etwa be *verschützen* (statt *beschützen*),  *Bezicht* (statt *Verzicht*, Assoziationen zu *bezichtigen* liegen nahe), *Haftverfehle* (statt *Haftbefehle*; ein Haftverfehl kann wohl als ein "verfehlter Haftbefehl" gedeutet werden) oder *Verleidigung* statt *Beleidigung* oder, in der prominenten Schlussphrase *verjahen* oder *beneinen*.

> Der Befassungsschutz verschützt die Versitzenden vor denen, die den Verhörden als bestockte Beschwörer verkannt sind, weil sie eine Beänderung der Lebensverdingungen wollen durch die Bewandlung der Produktionsbehältnisse. Ein wohlverstallter Veramtenapparat leistet Bezicht auf eigenes kritisches Denken die Herrschenden aber halten Verratungen ab, wie sie die Verherrschten davon abhalten können sich verdrückt und um ihr Leben vertrogen zu fühlen. Ein Heer von Bedummern will sie zur Selbstverherrschung erziehen und verarbeitet zu diesem Zweck die Normalbebraucher mit Verschwichtigungen und mit Betröstungen. Aber seht die Behafteten und ihre verwaffneten Verwacher und was die Gerichte bezapfen, vor die man sie stellt. Seht euch
> die Verweisbefahren an, die Haftverfehle und die Bestöße gegen das Grundrecht, seht die Verleidigung der Würde des Menschen und fragt euch dann ob ihr das verjahen wollt oder beneint.

(Die Zeilenumbrüche des Originals habe ich gestrichen, weil mir gerade keine Originalausgabe vorliegt.)

### Ist es klug?

Kreative Sprachverwendung birgt immer ein erhöhtes Risiko von Missverständnissen. Man sollte das machen, wenn man sich gut mit der Sprache auskennt, und wenn man vorhersagen kann, wie die eigene Wortschöpfung verstanden werden wird. Dieses Risiko ist bei der kreativen Verwendung von Präfixen besonders hoch, weil sich die Bedeutung eines Verbs mit Präfix sehr häufig nicht zurückführen lässt auf ein Modell "Bedeutung des Stammverbes plus Modifikation durch Präfix". Betrachte als ein schlagendes Beispiel dafür den Präfix *ver-* und einige Verben:

- *sich vergehen*
- *vergessen*
- *verzeihen*
- *vermessen* (ein Stück Land)
- *sich vermessen*
- *verwechseln*
- *verbrennen*
- *versinnbildlichen*
- etc.

Manche Präfixe haben eine derartige Varianz von Funktionen, dass man nicht von einer festen Funktion des Präfix sprechen kann.

Comment: "derartige Varianz von Funktionen, dass man nicht von einer festen Funktion des Präfix sprechen kann" - ich halte das nach wie vor für einen Mythos und finde, dass mir als Muttersprachler häufig genau diese (relativ!) feste Funktion der Präfixe dabei hilft, Wörter zu verstehen. Was aber tatsächlich der Fall ist, ist, dass gerade z.B. das genannte *ver-* eben nicht eine feste, sondern *zwei* sehr unterschiedliche "Standardbedeutungen" hat (die auch in den hier genannten Beispielen gut erkennbar sind) - einmal die "Prozessierung" von etwas, andererseits der "Fehlschlag" einer Aktion. Was ...

Comment: ... für das Vorhaben des OP ein Hindernis darstellt, ist (neben der [Mehrdeutigkeit durch die *zwei* festen Bedeutungen bei *ver-*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73943), die so bei anderen Präfixen wie z.B. *zer-* nicht gegeben ist) die Tatsache, dass die zusammengesetzte Form zum Teil schon eine feste sehr weit vom reinen Stammverb entfernte Bedeutung hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper bestellen, betreiben, besitzen, bekennen, verwenden, entscheiden, entzünden, und noch viele mehr. Der entscheidende Teil deines Kommentars steckt im Wort "relativ".

Comment: Kleine Anmerkung: Das Verb _eindenken_ gibt es schon.
[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eindenken) [Wictionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eindenken)

Answer (score 1):

> würden die Leute mich noch verstehen?

In einem Wort gesagt: nein! Das System von Vorsilben, speziell von Verbvorsilben ist komplex und historisch gewachsen. [Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/what-are-the-origin-possible-meanings-of-the-ver-prefix?rq=1) und [dort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76161/origin-and-meaning-of-prefix-ver/76187#76187) findest du etwa Herleitungen für die Vorsilbe "ver-".

Nur so als Beispiel: das von dir "erfundene" Wort "verwaschen" gibt es tatsächlich. Als Adjektiv bedeutet es "unscharf" oder "ohne klare Konturen", das Gegenteil von "fokussiert". etwa:

> Das Bild ist verwaschen.

Eine andere Bedeutung ist "durch oftmaliges Waschen haben die Farben ihre Leuchtkraft verloren" bzw. ein Effekt, der - figurativ - ebendiesem ähnelt.

Und das ist nur die Vorsilbe "ver-". Über diese wie auch andere Vorsilben, ihren Gebrauch, Entstehung und Bedeutung wurden meterweise Bücher geschrieben.

Ich an deiner Stelle würde, da kann ich @RHa nur beipflichten, die Finger davon lassen, solange du über eine Sprachkompetenz verfügst, die nicht einmal in die Nähe eines Muttersprachlers kommt. Hier etwa:

> Ich verwasche eine grasige Fleck [...].

Das ist Akkusativ und muß deshalb "eine*n* grasige*n* Fleck" heißen, davon abgesehen, daß "grasiger Fleck" hier nicht paßt. Ein "grasiger Fleck" ist eine Stelle in der Landschaft, wo Gras wächst. Was du meinst, ist ein "Grasfleck". Hier etwa aus Hugo von Hoffmannsthals Romanfragment "[Andreas oder die Vereinigten](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Hofmannsthal,+Hugo+von/Roman-Fragmhttp://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Hofmannsthal,+Hugo+von/Roman-Fragment/Andreas+oder+die+Vereinigten/Die+wunderbare+Freundinent/Andreas+oder+die+Vereinigten/Die+wunderbare+Freundin)":

> [...] grasige Berglehnen links und rechts, [...]

> An der Mauer dort war ein grasiger Fleck, [...]

Answer (score 1):

Das Verb *verwaschen* gibt es bereits, es bedeutet, dass man etwas unscharf macht. Unscharf wie ein Fleck, der gewaschen wurde. Normalerweise wird aber nur das Partizip II als Adjektiv benutzt.

Mit *verhassen* ist es wie mit *verwaschen*. Das Partizip II *verhasst* wird bereits als Adjektiv benutzt. Du kannst das Verb also nicht umdeuten.

Das von dir erfundene Verb *ausmerken* würde ich aus dem Zusammenhang für ein süddeutsches Dialektwort im Sinne von *bemerken* halten. Ich würde es deshalb nicht selbst benutzen.

Das von dir erfundene Verb *erquatschen* finde ich toll. Das ist sicher sowas wie *gemeinsam ein tolles Garn spinnen*. Ups, so meintest du das ja gar nicht. Tja, Pech gehabt. Ich benutze es jetzt so, wie ich es verstanden hab: „Agnes und Tina haben sich da wieder was erquatscht …“

Dein erfundenes Adjektiv *kleinchenlich* widerspricht den Bildungsregeln für solche Wörter. Meinst du *klitzekleinlich*? Steht nicht im Wörterbuch, hab' ich gerade aus *klitzeklein* und *kleinlich* erfunden. Werde ich jetzt auch öfters benutzen. Ganz allgemein solltest du Kofferworte verwenden, wenn du die deutsche Sprache kreativ erweitern willst. Die gehorchen nämlich den Bildungsregeln üblicherweise automatisch.

Answer (score 0):

*Können* kann man - wenn man's kann.

Ob man *sollte*: Eher nicht.

So leid mir's tut, wie bei jeder "Kunst" ist das Jonglieren mit Sprache etwas, das man erst dann tun kann, wenn man das "Handwerkszeug" absolut perfekt beherrscht.

Auch der Pianist, der konzertreif auswendig Beethoven-Sinfonien runterspielen kann, darf ein bißchen improvisieren und begeistert damit sein Publikum. Wenn's aber der Anfänger, der "für Elise" ins Klavier hämmert, tut, hört sich das leider nicht so gut an - ziemlich sicher hält dessen Publikum das einfach nur für einen Fehler.